# Book about aliens sending instructions to build a supercomputer

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens

I didn’t read it, so I could get it wrong. Here as I remember it:

People get in touch with aliens and they (aliens) send them instructions how to build supercomputer... But it appears to be evil and it’s purpose was to enslave humanity...

I’ve read a description and was going to read the book, but forgot about it and now I can’t find it.

Comment: This is a fairly common plot in science fiction.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It might be ["A for Andromeda"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_for_Andromeda), by Fred Hoyle and John Elliott. It started life as a TV mini-series, but was subsequently novelized. Here's the premise, from Wikipedia:

> A for Andromeda is a British television science fiction drama serial first made and broadcast by the BBC in seven parts in 1961. Written by cosmologist Fred Hoyle, in conjunction with author and television producer John Elliot, it concerns a group of scientists who detect a radio signal from another galaxy that contains instructions for the design of an advanced computer. When the computer is built, it gives the scientists instructions for the creation of a living organism named Andromeda, but one of the scientists, John Fleming, fears that Andromeda's purpose is to subjugate humanity.

Comment: Yeeeah! I guess so, I really thought that it starts with A. Thank you sooo much! :)

Comment: Happy I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly "
Out of the Dark" ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_of_the_Dark_(Weber_novel)

Comment: This doesn't seem like a good match as in that novel the aliens actually invade the Earth instead of just sending humanity the information necessary to create the means to destroy itself.